# How do i pass and retrieve id using vue js?

Tags: c#, vue.js, axios

I am trying to pass an id from 1 vue to another vue and get data for my api service.

I am able to pass the id from the 1st vue (ClientListing.vue) but somehow my 2nd vue (Client.vue) is not retrieve the id.

My ClientListing.vue

```
    <th scope="row" v-on:click="rowClicked(row)" style="cursor: pointer"> 
       <div class="media align-items-center" @click="showClient(row)">
          <a class="avatar rounded-circle mr-3">
              <img alt="Image placeholder" :src="row.customerTypeIcon">
          </a>
          <div class="media-body">
              <span class="name mb-0 text-sm">{{row.name}}</span>
          </div>
       </div>
    </th>

methods: {
   showClient(item) {
   router.push({ path: 'Clients/client', query: { id: item.id } });
   }
}
```

My Client.vue

```
mounted: function () {
   CifRepository
   .getCustomerDetails(this.$route.query)
   .then(response => {
      this.model = response.data.Results;
   }
)
.catch(error => {
   console.log(error)
   this.errored = true
})
.finally(() => this.loading = false);
}
```

```
getCustomerDetails(id) {
   return Repository.get("/api/Accounts/GetCustomerDetails");
}
```

My api service - AccountsController

```
[HttpGet("GetCustomerDetails")]
public async Task<CustomerListingDto> GetCustomerDetails(long id)
{

   CustomerServiceModel customers = await
   _accountService.GetCustomerDetailsByCustomerId(id);

   return _mapper.Map<CustomerListingDto>(customers);
}
```

My AccountController/GetCustomerDetails keep on getting 0/null value and could not get the id pass from the ClientListing.vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `this.$route.query.id` instead of `this.$route.query`

```
mounted: function () {
  CifRepository
  .getCustomerDetails(this.$route.query.id)
  .then(response => {
    this.model = response.data.Results;
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
    this.errored = true
  })
  .finally(() => this.loading = false);
}
```

and

```
getCustomerDetails(id) {
   return Repository.get("/api/Accounts/GetCustomerDetails/" + id);
}
```

I'm not sure with C# part, but it might be

```
[HttpGet("GetCustomerDetails/${id}")]
public async Task<CustomerListingDto> GetCustomerDetails(long id)
{

   CustomerServiceModel customers = await
   _accountService.GetCustomerDetailsByCustomerId(id);

   return _mapper.Map<CustomerListingDto>(customers);
}
```

Comment: After i changed it to this.$route.query.id it still the same. The GetCustomerDetails still receive 0/null value.

Comment: Did you send id in `getCustomerDetails`?

Comment: This works. I managed to pass the id to GetCustomerDetails. Thank you.